# How to refresh figure in Bokeh?

Tags: button, bokeh, figure

I have the following code in Bokeh. It displays four dots in red. The user can select another color from the dropdown, click 'Run' and the dots are to change color.
With this code, the dots do not change color nor does the image_1.png get updated.
Any advise on how I could refresh image_1.png and display it correctly?
Thanks indeed!

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import (Select, Button)

from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

from bokeh.layouts import column, layout
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_range=(0,100)
y_range=(0,100)

color_1 = ['red','blue','yellow']
N = 4
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 10
y = np.random.random(size=N) * 10
radii = 15#np.random.random(size=N) * 15

line_color = Select(value='red',
                        title='color:',
                        width=200,
                        options=color_1)

p = figure(tools="reset,pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select")

file_name_1 = "test_sp/static/image_1.png"

def button_callback():
    print('bc')
    p = figure(tools="reset,pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select")
    layout.children[1] = create_figure()
    return p




def create_figure():
    c1 = line_color.value
    print(c1)
    file_name_1 = "test_sp/static/image_1.png"
    plt.scatter(x,y,radii,color=c1,alpha=0.6)
    
    plt.savefig(file_name_1)
    p = figure(tools="reset,pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select")
    p.image_url(url=[file_name_1],x=x_range[0],y=y_range[1],w=x_range[1]-x_range[0],h=y_range[1]-y_range[0])
    return p
  

    
button = Button(label='Run', width=100, button_type="success")



button.on_click(button_callback)


selects = column(line_color,button, width=420)
layout=row(selects, create_figure())

curdoc().add_root(layout)

curdoc().title = "color the dots"
```

Edit 1: The code I posted here is the complete minimal example of a much larger code where I update the Bokeh figure (based on user inputs from the front-end, save it and then refresh the front-end).
This is why I have a ‘run’ button in the front-end (to collect the user inputs) and a create figure() in the Bokeh code to allow me to construct a Bokeh figure (which is a .png saved from a matplotlib plot).  I still need the 'run' button and create_figure(). My issue is that even though the .png gets updated on the server side, I am unable to refresh the front end with this updated .png. Any advise you may have on how to refresh the Bokeh figure..?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are mixing `matplotlib` and `bokeh`. You have to solve this problem. And if you want to use callback with bokeh, you have to use `JavaScript` and not `Python` callbacks. To write you own callback your have to write this line `from bokeh.models import CustomJS`. But the plot you are asking for is also possible without `CustomJS`.

**Example**

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.plotting import  figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

import numpy as np 

color_1 = ['red','blue','green']
N = 4
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=N)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=N)

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
points = p.scatter(x,y, fill_color='red', line_color=None)

select = Select(title="Color:", value="red", options=color_1,  width=80)
select.js_link('value', points.glyph, 'fill_color')
layout=row(select, p)

show(layout)
```

| **red** | **blue** | **green** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: red] | [image: blue] | [image: green] |

Comment: Thank you @mosc9575 ! I did not know I could not mix Bokeh and matplotlib! Since  I run my code as a Bokeh application on a Bokeh server from a single Python script using bokeh serve, I modified your code to add curdoc and curdoc().add_root(layout). This works ok. (I have edited my question for further clarification)